# What is a Trending Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Trending Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Trending Words™ | Not Trending Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| JUDO | KEY |
| WHO | IRK |
| BURN | EAT |
| MUD | TALK |
| UNITE | TIDY |
| PURE | TOO |
| GLOAT | HAPPY |
| MUCH | LEND |
| HI | LIKE |
| QUOTE | SAY |
| DIE | SHRUG |
| BAE | SHAME |
| FUCHSIA | SNOW |
| NOTE | GRAPE |
| QUIT | VAN |
| WOE | PERF |
| WHOA | FLAME |
| VAT | TRUMP |

And, if you want to analyse, here is a CSV version:

```
Trending Words™,Not Trending Words™
JUDO,KEY
WHO,IRK
BURN,EAT
MUD,TALK
UNITE,TIDY
PURE,TOO
GLOAT,HAPPY
MUCH,LEND
HI,LIKE
QUOTE,SAY
DIE,SHRUG
BAE,SHAME
FUCHSIA,SNOW
NOTE,GRAPE
QUIT,VAN
WOE,PERF
WHOA,FLAME
VAT,TRUMP
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A word is a Trending Word™ if

> The letters of the word are in increasing order of frequency, using the list of letters at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency.

Comment: Perhaps the @Jezzamon could decide whether "soot" is a Trending Word™.

Comment: You got it! I chose to limit examples to words that were 'strictly' trending, so that wouldn't include soot.